# <a4j:commandbutton> action property isn't called after adding <h:message> and ajax event to a required inputtext

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Inside a `<a4j:outputPanel>` I have a disabled inputtext that displays `Authors` from a `List<Author>` that belongs to the class `DocumentBean`. I have also a `<h:selectOneMenu>` that displays names of Authors. When an Author from the menu is selected the Author is added to the `List<Author>` I mentioned above, and a new disabled `inputtext` appears.

Here's the code described above:

```
  Autor:
          <a4j:outputPanel id="teste">
            <a4j:repeat value="#{insertDocController.docController.documentBean.authorList}" var="author">
            <br />
            <h:inputText value="#{author.name}" disabled="true" />
             <br />
             <a4j:commandButton type="submit" action="#{insertDocController.removeAutor(author.uri)}" 
             value="Remover" render="teste" />
            </a4j:repeat>

          <br />
            <h:selectOneMenu id="chooseAuthor" value="#{insertDocController.selectedAuthorUri}">
                  <f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true" itemLabel="selecione" itemValue=""/>
                  <f:selectItems value="#{insertDocController.authorValues}" var="author"
                  itemValue="#{author.uri}" itemLabel="#{author.name}"/>     
               </h:selectOneMenu> 
           <a4j:commandButton type="submit" action="#{insertDocController.addAuthor()}"
            value="Inserir" render="teste" />
            <br />
          </a4j:outputPanel>
```

Here's the addAuthor() from insertDocController:

```
public void addAuthor() {   
          if(this.selectedAuthorUri != null) {
                AuthorBean a = new AuthorBean();
                a.setUri(this.selectedAuthorUri);
                a.setName(this.authMapper.searchNameByAuthorUri(this.selectedAuthorUri));
                this.docController.getDocumentBean().addAuthor(a);
              }                                                     
    }
```

On that same `xhtml` page there's an inputtext. Everything was working properly, when the inputtext was like this:

```
Title: <h:inputText id="input"
        value="#{insertDocController.docController.documentBean.title}">
        </h:inputText>
```

But stopped working properly since I set the inputtext to be required and added a message to it, like this:

```
   Title: <h:inputText id="input"
            value="#{insertDocController.docController.documentBean.title}"
            required="true" requiredMessage="Campo Obrigatorio">
            <f:ajax  execute="@this input" render="message" event="blur"/>
            </h:inputText>         
            <h:message for="input" id="message" style="color:red"/>
```

After I changed the title inputtext, when I choose an Author on the `<h:selectedOneMenu>` it simply doesn't call the action method `addAuthor()` from the `<a4j:commandbutton>` inside the  `<h:selectedOneMenu>`.

(That's the line with the action method that isn't called - It was extracted from the above code I gave you at first):

```
<a4j:commandButton type="submit" action="#{insertDocController.removeAutor(author.uri)}" 
             value="Remover" render="teste" />
```

If I turn the inputtext as it was before it starts to work again. 
What may be the problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the `execute` attribute.

*Delete Author*

```
<a4j:commandButton type="submit" action="#{insertDocController.removeAutor(author.uri)}" 
         value="Remover" render="teste" execute="@this"> 
</a4j:commandButton>
```

*For the add author button*

```
<a4j:commandButton type="submit" action="#{insertDocController.addAuthor()}"
        value="Inserir" render="teste" execute="@this, chooseAuthor">
</a4j:commandButton>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi!I read your last posts, and I applied the changes you suggested with immediate on remove() , addAuthor() and <h:selectedOneMenu>. After I did it, it started to call the method addAction, but the value selected in the <h:selectedOneMenu> was always null.

Comment: yes because I was confused by the request of the question, I updated the answer with the right way. please review @Luciane

Comment: I'm using JAVAX 2, RICHFACES 4.3.3 and MOJARRA 1.2. My <a4j:commandButton> doesn't have a process property, it has an execute property. I used the execute as you said and now it's working. Thank you so much! You helped a lot!

Comment: Oh yes, I had the wrong version documentation, it's been a long time for me since I used Richfaces :D it's Primefaces days now

Comment: ok! I didn't know that Primefaces was more used these days..I started with JSF just now and choose it cause I found it beautiful.. nice knowing

Comment: @Luciane are you sure you're using JSF 1.2 and RichFaces 4? AFAIK that combination won't even work to begin with =\

Comment: Of course she meant 2.1 :) otherwise she wouldn't get far to ask such question. ;) @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: Yes, I'm using the 2.0 version, it's because the name of the jar is javax.faces.2.0.11, and I confused myself. I have a mojarra 1.2 jar but it's not in my project, just in the computer.